# Asynchronously load UIViews

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiview, asynchronous, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to load views asynchronously.  The problem is that the frame of the views to be loaded depends on the data that's loaded asynchronously.  In other words there are some long calculations that decide where to actually display the UIViews.

I know that there are problems when trying to actually display a UIView in a thread and that you should always load them back in the main thread, so this is the code I've been trying out:

```
asyncQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[asyncQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Do work to load the UIViews and figure out where they should be
    UIButton *test = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:[self doWorkToGetFrame]];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self addSubview:test];
        }
    }];
}];
```

This all resides in a UIView container.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Apple says UIKit is not thread safe. That would imply loading nibs containing UI elements (to me at least). Why don't you do all your calculations in operations or blocks, run then concurrently and in the background, but post the results to the main thread where the actual views can be loaded, configured, and shown. Doing anything with UIKit in threads may work now but break in the next point release of iOS. You can for sure refactor your code to do as I suggest.

Comment: I'll certainly give it a try, in the past when it happened, parts of things added in the main queue would show up a good couple of seconds after the others, but I'll try putting all of the necessary parameters in an array and then loading the views themselves in the mianQueue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UIButton *test = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
test.hidden = YES;
test.alpha = 0.0f;
[self addSubview:test];

dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myDownloadQueue",NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^
{
  // do work to load UIViews and calculate frame
  CGRect frameButton = ...;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
  {
    test.hidden = NO; 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^
    {
     test.frame = frameButton;
     test.alpha = 1.0f;
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){}];


  });
});

dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

This adds your button in the main thread, but makes it invisible initially.  After your background work is done, you'll make it visible and set the frame using an animation.

Comment: Right, this is essentially exactly what I ended up doing!  Thanks!